# Django in-memory model, not for tests

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-cache

I have a model whose instances don't need to be written to database, ever. They are generated on the fly, very cheaply, and almost never change.

I wish to query these instances via the ORM and also browse them in django-admin (read-only + mass_actions, no need for CRUD).

From what I gathered, SQLite uses in-memory database when running tests. I think I want to use this feature, just not limited to tests.

Another option might be a pure in-memory model backend, but I'm not finding one. Actually I did find this project: https://github.com/felipecruz/dmqs It looks a bit dated though.

Or maybe there is a caching backend that can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the special file name :memory: to instruct sqlite to use an in memory database.

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': ':memory:',
  }
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Ha! This looks perfect! Thanks, I'll try it out soon.